# Hyper-parameter optimization in tensorflow object detection API

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection, object-detection-api, hyperparameters

Is there any way to specify hyper-parameter optimisation like Hyperopt or other in the config file of object detection API to fine tune the model?

Answer (score 3):

You can change following hyper parameters for object detection:

- learning rate
- momentum
- optimizer
- decay factor
- matched_threshold
- unmatched_threshold